# Will a mysqldump ever break my database?

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

I tried to backup my database with mysqldump. I've done this on a live website also. Is there any chance that this command could ever break a website/database?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by that. It certainly will not change or corrupt the data stored inside the database server. Simply because it only has read-only access. however it could be that it interferes with other programs, since it blocks tables. So if these other programs are of low quality (to keep things simple here) issue might arise. The answer is different if you are concerned about the content of the _dumped_ database. That depends on a whole lot of other things, actually.

Comment: I used ssh to dump database. Wasn't 100% sure if it would change the data or mess with the tables. Is the command only read only then?

Comment: @MaxSmtih It is a backup utility. Why would it change the data? Backup utilities are part of the solution to database corruption, not part of the problem.

Comment: @EJP Whilst you have a point there I still would say that your way of reasoning is, well, questionable. Rifles are also often considered part of some defense. Still they kill people.

Answer (score 1):

The `mysqldump` utility will not break your database.

Read the source code for it and/or turn on the general query log while it's running and you'll see that what all it does it look.

But...

If you are using MyISAM, or if you fail to use the `--single-transaction` option, or you issue a `FLUSH TABLES;` request from another connection while the backup is reading a large table, you stand a higher chance of *stalling* your web site because there are things that can happen to cause queries to block until the specific table or the entire backup is complete.

And, if you do have serious corruption in your data, `mysqldump` stands a good chance of running into it, since it reads every row from every table by default, which means the server will be trying to read through the corruption and could crash.  This is essentially true of any backup, of course.

But directly and ordinarily and by most reasonable definitions, mysqldump cannot harm your database contents.